# Open vertical splits to the right

Tags: spacemacs, evil, window-splitting

Using `spacemacs` with Evil. `:vsp` opens a new split vertical, but it always does it to the left. How can one configure it to open them to the right?

Answer (score 5):

```
(setq evil-vsplit-window-right t)
```

Now, I can't tell you where to put this because I don't use Spacemacs, but I'm reasonably sure you already know.